# Javascript sort object array

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
  private restorePurchases(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
      let data: any[] =
        [
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.30days',
            date: 1499869861370
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
            date: 1498869861369
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.10days',
            date: 1499869851369
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
            date: 1499869861369
          }
        ];

      resolve(data);
    });
  }
```

As you can see, it returns an array. I would like to sort the array by `date` (ascending).

```
this.restorePurchases().then((purchases: any[]) => {
    purchases.sort(by date);
});
```

Any advise welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Unless for some reason TypeScript prevents it, you should be using `return Promise.resolve(...)` instead of constructing a new promise and then invoking its `resolve` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how [`Array.prototype.sort` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
this.restorePurchases().then((purchases: any[]) => {
     purchases.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.30days',
    date: 1499869861370
  },
  {
    productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
    date: 1498869861369
  },
  {
    productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.10days',
    date: 1499869851369
  },
  {
    productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
    date: 1499869861369
  }
];

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I will mark this as the correct answer in 9 minutes when it allows me to.